# Remove url extras when submitting form

Tags: php, url

I have a scenario where when I submit a form in PHP, sometimes the url would be something like this prior to submitting:

```
http://localhost/pre_school-schedules.php#ps-n2
```

What I want to do is set the url after submitting to be as follows:

```
http://localhost/pre_school-schedules.php
```

Currently I'm trying to do that with:

```
header('Location:http://localhost/pre_school-schedules.php');
```

But this is not working and prevents my custom messages such as `Item inserted successfully.` or `there was a problem with...` to show. Is there any other way to make the page after a post request remove any extra stuff from the URL?

Comment: post should not add anything to the url, are you sure the form action is correct.

Comment: The url sometimes is like that because I use anchoring on the same page (when a link is clicked, I send them to a specific part of that page). I updated my question

Comment: you should be able to change the form action (a fixed url rather than the current pages), so this does not happen

Comment: I'm not using an action attribute on my form tag. I capture the `$_POST['submitButton']` on the same file and just send all data to different functions on other files.

Comment: well then it defaults to the current page, and that's the problem if the current page has the # in it, so use a form action. `action="pre_school-schedules.php"` should solve this

Comment: This works. Put is an answer and I will mark it as such! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as you don't define the post action, the current url is used, if it has a fragment (the bit after the #) that gets  sent also. So simply hard code the action like so:

```
action="pre_school-schedules.php"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to remove the anchor and everything after it during your form processing with preg_replace, trim, or similar function.

```
$url = preg_replace('/#.*/', '', $url);
```

If you end up needing to redirect, save your needed data such as errors in a session then send them to the destination page.